# A WolframKernel (with PID) is created by a LocalSubmit. After the LocalSubmit finishes its job, the kernel remains. How to kill it within Mathematica?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

When defining a task with `LocalSubmit`, a new subkernel is created. When you remove the task after the task is done, the task is removed but the subkernel remains open.

`CloseKernals[]` doesn't do anything, and `$KernelCount` also returns `0`. The only way I could terminate the subkernal is by killing the process of that subkernel in OS process manager (e.g., Task Manager on Windows and htop in Linux.)

How can I neatly terminate the subkernel within Mathematica, without having to find its PID and force-kill it on OS process manager?

Comment: `LocalSubmit[Pause[10] ; Quit[], HandlerFunctions->Association["TaskFinished"->0],HandlerFunctionsKeys->"EvaluationResult"]`, staff after code is to suppress dialog window popup